# MLP Loss calculated as NaN

Tags: python, neural-network, time-series, tf.keras

I am trying to prepare a MLP model for a time-series data. Its parameters are:

1. Model is Sequential
2. Layers:
   a- Hidden layer: One dense layer, with 100 nodes

   - input_dim = flattened array of my input whose dimensions are (number of timesteps * number of variables). In my case it is (10*2)
   - Activation function: relu
     b- Output layer: dense layer with only one node
3. Compile: optimizer is "adam" and loss is "mse"

Here is my complete code for the building of the MLP:

```
# preparing the model
# flatten input
n_input = X.shape[1] * X.shape[2]
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], n_input))

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=n_input))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100, verbose= 'auto')
```

Details on my data shape and sample:

- Shape: `print(X.shape, y.shape)` gives `(2581654, 10, 2) (2581654,)`
- sample of the data: It is
  X:

```
[[[71.22222222  0.57692308]
  [71.89583333  0.9       ]
  [71.40138889  0.96666667]
  ...
  [70.63630437  3.06666667]
  [65.2247619   3.86666667]
  [65.22804233  3.66666667]]

 [[71.89583333  0.9       ]
  [71.40138889  0.96666667]
  [71.36721612  1.03333333]
  ...
  [65.2247619   3.86666667]
  [65.22804233  3.66666667]
  [67.0974359   2.2       ]]

 [[71.40138889  0.96666667]
  [71.36721612  1.03333333]
  [70.44217687  1.96666667]
  ...
  [65.22804233  3.66666667]
  [67.0974359   2.2       ]
  [68.32787879  3.26666667]]
```

y:

```
[ 90.  62.  89. ... 225. 211. 221.]
```

Problem: During training, my loss is being reported as nan. Here is a sample of the output:

```
Epoch 1/100
80677/80677 [==============================] - 187s 2ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 2/100
80677/80677 [==============================] - 182s 2ms/step - loss: nan
Epoch 3/100
35140/80677 [============>.................] - ETA: 1:43 - loss: nan
```

I am expecting that the loss be a numerical value, not NaN. I made sure that my data types are of the correct format. Running `x.dtype` and `y.dtype` return `dtype('float64')`.

I thought of normalizing my outputs, but I don't see how this will help my case as I did not need to normalize my output for uni-variate MLP.

Comment: It looks fine to me, feel free to self-accept when the system allows you to. From what I recall, automatic question bans and automatic answer bans are calculated separately, so I don't think a up/downvoted answer would affect your ability to ask questions.

Comment: (If you have any self-deleted questions, there may be value in undeleting them and improving them, in the hope they attract upvotes. This will feed into the question ban algorithm and possibly get you unbanned. But of course it is a risky game, since some downvotes are just capricious and there's not a lot you can do about them).

Comment: Got it. I appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensuring the replacement or removing of any NaN values worked for me. I am no longer getting a loss value of "NaN". I have also standardized both the inputs and outputs of my MLP. Below is the code I used:

1. Removing NaN values:

   ```
   nan_check = df[['volume', 'speed', 'occupancy']].isna().any(axis=1)

   df = df[~nan_check]
   ```
2. Standardizing the input and output features:

   ```
   from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

   # Flatten your input data if it's 3D

   if X.ndim == 3:

    num_samples, num_time_steps, num_features = X.shape
    X = X.reshape(num_samples, num_time_steps * num_features)

   input_scaler = StandardScaler()

   X_scaled = input_scaler.fit_transform(X)  # X should be your input data

   #Create a scaler for the output data:

   output_scaler = StandardScaler()
   y_scaled = output_scaler.fit_transform(y.reshape(-1, 1))  # y should be your output data
   ```